# About Matlab "intlinprog" function

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a math problem that give me a minimal value of a function. The function is `min y = x1 + x2 + x3 +...+ x14`. The invariants are:

```
2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 ≥ 28 
x_4+ x_5 + 2x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 ≥ 79
x_3 + x_5 + 2x_7 + x_8 + 4x_10 + 3x_11 + 2x_12 + x_13 ≥ 46
x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 + x_6 + 2x_8 + 3x_9 + x_11 + 2x_12 + 4x_13 + 5x_14 ≥ 33
```

so I write the Matlab code like this:

```
fun = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1];
intcon = 14;
a = [-2 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 -1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0;...
    0 0 -1 0 -1 0 -2 -1 0 -4 -3 -2 -1 0; -1 -3 -2 -1 0 -1 0 -2 -3 0 -1 -2 -4 -5];
b = [-28;-79;-46;-33];
[x,fval] = intlinprog(fun,intcon,a,b)
```

but when I run this code it gives me following error:

> Intlinprog stopped because the root LP problem is unbounded.
>
> x =
>
> ```
>  []
> ```
>
> fval =
>
> ```
>  []
> ```

but I have found the solution which `x5 = 28,x6 = 23,x8 = 5,x10 = 4` and `min y = 60`

What causes the error? If I want to get the right answer (`xi` must be an integer), what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimizer complains that the problem is unbounded, a good thing to try to figure out is in what direction the objective function is able to improve indefinitely. In your case the objective function is the sum of all your variables and the warning about an unbounded minimization problem therefore means that one or more of your variables are decreasing towards negative infinity while still being an valid point according to the constraints.

This sort of small thought experiment might be helpful when trying to figure out what's wrong with the problem formulation. I am guessing you meant to include minimum bounds for your variables, `0 <= x_i`? Include lower and upper bounds of your variables by specifying the `lb` and `ub` input parameters to `intlinprog()`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I fixed it by adding lb and ub parameters.You are right I forgot including minimum bounds for my variables.